# What causes SQL syntax error 1064 in this go code?

Tags: go, mariadb

I'm trying to insert data into my table
(I'm using MariaDB)

```
func (r *UserRepository) Create(u *model.User) (*model.User, error) {
if err := r.store.db.QueryRow(
    "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES ('$1', '$2', MD5('$3')) RETURNING `id`;",
    u.Email,
    u.Username,
    u.Password,
).Scan(&u.ID); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return u, nil
```

}

and test says

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURNING `id`' at line 1

also I have almost the same problem with other line

```
if _, err := s.db.Exec(fmt.Sprintf("TRUNCATE %s CASCADE", strings.Join(tables, ", "))); err != nil {
            t.Fatal(err)
        }
```

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASCADE' at line 1

Comment: In the insert the single-quotes around the ordinal parameters seem like they don't belong there, but I'm not sure if that's what's causing the syntax error. And btw. what driver are you using?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `;` at the end of the statement? As to the second statement, MariaDB [`TRUNCATE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/truncate-table/) 1) accepts a single table name, not a list of table names and 2) doesn't have a `CASCADE` clause.

Comment: only mariadb supports it since MariaDB 10.5.0

Comment: @nbk OP says they're using MariaDB and this is also reflected in the error message. Maybe they're using a MariaDB version that doesn't support `RETURNING` (which was introduced in 10.5.0)?

Comment: and truncate has no cascade

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB 10.1.48. Thanks for this, now I need an update.
Also I had other tabs in my table, so I fixed my code ""INSERT INTO `users` (`uuid`, `id`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `accessToken`, `serverID`, `hwidId`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '$1', '$2', '$3', NULL, NULL, NULL)", but now there is an other problem - "sql: expected 0 arguments, got 3"

Comment: Now, I think, I should have used Postgres...

Comment: @deep the reason for the `expected 0 arguments, got 3` error is because you've wrapped the ordinal parameter references in single quotes. That makes them literal strings rather than placeholders to be replaced by the arguments you pass to the `QueryRow` method. So the first thing you need to do is to remove the single quotes around the placeholders, i.e. change `'$1'` to `$1` and so on. Also, because you are using MariaDB, you should actually be using the mysql specific parameter placeholder instead of the ordinal references, i.e. change `$N` to `?`.

Comment: @deep if you do opt to use postgres instead of maria, then you can keep using the ordinal parameter references, just keep in mind that you still need to remove the single quotes from around those parameter references.